# Zend Framework 2 FormElementManager factories not working

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form-element

Please help me with Zend framework 2:)

I want to create a form with collection of fieldsets using Form Element Manager (absolutely like [in official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html)).

My FormElementManager configuration:

```
'form_elements' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Admin\Form\TaskForm' => function($sm) {
            $form = new TaskForm();
            $doctrimeEntityManager = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
            $form -> setEntityManager($doctrimeEntityManager);
            $form -> init();
            return $form;
        },
        'Admin\Form\TaskbrandFieldset' => function($sm) {
            $doctrimeEntityManager = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
            $form = new TaskbrandFieldset();
            $form->setEntityManager($doctrimeEntityManager);
            return $form;
        },
    )
),
```

Admin\Form\TaskForm (only problem part):

```
namespace Admin\Form;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class TaskForm extends Form {

protected $entityManager;

public function init() {

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    // Id
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
        ),
    ));

    // My fieldset
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'taskbrands',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Brand of the product',
            'count' => 0,
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'target_element' => array(
                'type'=>'Admin\Form\TaskbrandFieldset'
                ),
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'addressFieldset'
        )
    ));
}
}
```

Admin\Form\TaskbrandFieldset:

```
namespace Admin\Form;

use Admin\Entity\Taskbrand;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class TaskbrandFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

protected $entityManager;
protected $serviceLocator;

public function init() {
    $this->setName('TaskbrandFieldset');
    $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
            ->setObject(new Taskbrand());

    $this->setLabel('Taskbrand');

    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'name' => 'brand',
        'options' => array(
            'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
            'target_class' => 'Module\Entity\Brand',
            'property' => 'name',
        ),
    ));

}
}
```

And, finally, my controller:

```
 $Task = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Admin\Model\Task')->findByPk($id);
 $formManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager');
 $form =  $formManager->create('Admin\Form\TaskForm');
 $form->bind($Task);
```

The problem is that form Admin\Form\TaskForm instantiates in factory described in form_elements configuration section, but Admin\Form\TaskbrandFieldset does not. It just invokes.

Trying to understand this problem I found that Admin\Form\TaskForm and Admin\Form\TaskbrandFieldset instantiates with different instances of FormElementManager, first one have my config inside (including factories description), but second has nothing.

Please help me :)

Comment: The Form**Element**Manager is to create Form **Elements** ;) Use a normal Service Factory to create your forms (service_manager => factories)

Comment: I've tried. If using normal service factory (in controller $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Admin\Form\TaskForm')) TaskForm instantiates right, but Admin\Form\TaskbrandFieldset is still instantiates with FormElementManager with no config. In   [official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#handling-dependencies) they use FormElementManager.

Comment: Hmm, personally i do it like pointed out in the [DoctrineDocs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform) and simply instantiate the Fieldset in my Form which  already knows about the EntityManager so it's easy to pass it along.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your controller. Use

```
$form = $formManager->get('Admin\Form\TaskForm');
```

instead of

```
$form = $formManager->create('Admin\Form\TaskForm');
```

Remember that you don't have to use $form->init(). It's automatically called, same like in zf1. There is a good tutorial on [zf2 site](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html)